# Initializing Sub Class Through A Method

Tags: vba

I a routine which has a class foo.  Class foo contains class bar, but does not initialize it.  In my routine, I pass in as an object the parent method's foo's class bar.  The receiving method then initializes foo's bar as a new bar.

For some reason, when I later reference foo, bar is not initialized.  Is there anyway to initialize foo's bar within another method?

```
<Class Foo>
Option Explicit

Public mybar As Bar

<Class Bar>
Option Explicit

Public theText As String

<Main Module>
Public Sub Test()
  Dim myfoo As New foo
  Dim abar As Bar


  Derp myfoo.mybar


  myfoo.mybar.theText = "Test"
End Sub

Public Sub Derp(ByRef mybar As Bar)
  Set mybar = New Bar

End Sub
```

When the code encounters myfoo.mybar.thetext = "Test", I receive an error 91, Object variable or With block variable not set.

I'm using VBA through a vendor specific system, VBA version 6.5.1054.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get you code working you need to make quite small improvements. You need to completely initialize `bar class` within `foo class`. Therefore instead of this line:

```
Public mybar As Bar
```

change it into this one:

```
Public mybar As New Bar
```

However, there are some more to improve in your `Main Module`. Therefore I did it this way and it works:

```
Public Sub Test()
  Dim myfoo As New foo
  Dim abar As New Bar

  myfoo.mybar.theText = "Test"
End Sub
```

If you need to keep `Derp` sub then your `abar variable` must be public.

**Edit after comment**
Now I have better understanding of your needs therefore I would propose to solve it this way.

1. Keep the `bar class` unchanged
2. `Foo class` requires additional method which allows to initialize `boo class` when you need it. Complete `Foo class` code:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public mybar As Bar

   Sub BarInit()
       Set mybar = New Bar
   End Sub
   ```
3. Your `Main module` should than looks like code below (take a look at comments inside the Sub):

   ```
   Public Sub Test()


       Dim myfoo As New Foo

       'this will not work at this stage, _
       kept to show the problem, Error 91, _
       please remove it after test
       myfoo.mybar.theText = "test"

       'initialize Bar class within Foo class _
       using Foo class method
       myfoo.BarInit

       'now will work as it's initialized
       myfoo.mybar.theText = "test"
       Debug.Print myfoo.mybar.theText
   End Sub
   ```

As you can see initialisation is still kept within `foo class` but called only when required by calling `BarInit method`.

Comment: I'm purposefully not initializing bar within foo as in some cases, bar does not exist and I test if it is nothing.  Foo actually contains three different bars, and I was hoping I could generalize some methods that could be called on all three bars by passing in the appropriate bar.  It looks like that probably isn't possible.